# Git - push tags in Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans

I want to push git tags in netbeans. In console I can use it with `git push origin --tags`.

How can I do it from the IDE? I'm using Netbeans 8.0.

Answer (score 7):

Well - it's quite a while ago since you asked that question but I just ran into that question as well and found an answer. Hope it will help somebody facing the same issue:

Right click your project > Git > Remote > Push ... > Select remote repository > Your tags will appear here: Select tags to push!! > Push

Comment: Hmm I already switched to Jetbrains long time ago ;) But thanks anyway, I will check it out in some free time and accept your answer. Though I'm curious if it was always there, or is this some new feature in new version of Netbeans?

Comment: Heheh, probably you are right and this feature came with the last update (I'm using 8.0.2) :) I can't really get used to Jetbrains but should definitely give it a try again since the git support in netbeans is quite basic.